# How to fix in laravel 5.2 zizaco entrust:migration class name validation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, entrust

I have followed zizac/entrust installation tutorial from GitHub [Link](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) and faced  with error:

> Class name must be a valid object or a string in
>   var/www/html/laravel_test/vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php
>   on line 86

MigrationCommand.php file url : [Link](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php)

Outut:

```
php artisan entrust:migration

Tables: roles, role_user, permissions, permission_role
A migration that creates 'roles', 'role_user', 'permissions', 'permission_role' tables will be created in database/migrations directory

Proceed with the migration creation? [Yes|no] (yes/no) [yes]: yes

Creating migration...
PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /var/www/html/laravel_test/vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php on line 86
```

the command: *php artisan vendor:publish* was successful.

File : config/entrust.php exist.

I didin't change any options to config/auth.php file same as - [auth.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L31-L44). How to fix it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

in vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php on line 86

remove line :

```
    $usersTable  = Config::get('auth.table');
    $userModel   = Config::get('auth.model');
```

add line :

```
$usersTable  = Config::get('auth.providers.users.table');
$userModel   = Config::get('auth.providers.users.model');
```

and config/auth.php file write provider line as like me :

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'users',
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

then your problem will solve : happy coding

Comment: This solve the problem. I'm on Laravel 5.2 and using multi auth. This works like charm! Thanks

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It is working fine with laravel 5.2..This should be marked as right answer..:-)

Comment: @taposghosh, It gives the same error on role->delete() operation. Where else do I need change?

Comment: You should not edit direct vendor files as they will be overwritten in future updates. Instead you should add the correct lines to the config file until an update by Entrust updates their codebase to use the newer Laravel auth layout.

Comment: you save me bro

Comment: works in laravel 5.4.... following @BradBird. added in `code` config/auth.php`code`
`code`

/*
     * CONFIG FOR ENTRUST:MIGRATION
     *
     * */

    'table' => 'users',
    'model' => App\Models\Usuario::class

`code`

Answer (score 5):

In vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php on line 86.

Laravel 5.1.* Add Line

```
$usersTable  = Config::get('auth.table');
$userModel   = Config::get('auth.model');
```

Laravel 5.2.* Add Line

```
$usersTable  = Config::get('auth.providers.users.table');
$userModel   = Config::get('auth.providers.users.model');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer may fix the problem but it is very bad practice to edit direct vendor files. The following will fix the issue you may be having and will support your app still working if you decide to update Entrust and they fix their codebase.

Add the following lines to **config/auth.php** underneath:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/
```

Laravel 5.1 - 5.4

```
'model' => \App\Models\User::class,
'table' => 'users',
```

Once Entrust rolls out an update you can remove this or keep it. Up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try running:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

to make sure your application is using fresh config files

**EDIT**

Ok, now I see, this library want to use:

```
  $usersTable  = Config::get('auth.table');
  $userModel   = Config::get('auth.model');
```

but there is no something like this in `auth` any more.

So as temporary workaround you should probaby add `table` and `model` to `auth` file like so: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/config/auth.php

and wait until Entrust will be upgraded to remove this

Comment: Thanks, still same problem. I think problem is with config/auth.php file.

Comment: Could you show your `User.php` file? It should be in `App` namespace