# Laravel 5.2 with Entrust - Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: php, laravel, user-roles, entrust

I have a problem when register a user, after save user in my table users, I try assign role for this user but I receive the error :

> Class name must be a valid object or a string.

my code is

> (App\Http\Controllers\auth\AuthController.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Role;

use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function postRegister(Request $request){

            $this->validate($request,[
                'name' => 'required|min:4|max:255|unique:users',
                'email'=>'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password'=>'required|confirmed|min:3'
                ]);

            $user_data = array(
               //$field => $request->input('login'),
               'name'=> $request->input('name'),
               'email' => $request->input('email'),
               'password' => $request->input('password')
            );

            $user=User::create([
                    'name'=>$user_data['name'],
                    'email'=>$user_data['email'],
                    'password'=>bcrypt($user_data['password']),
                    'active'=>1                
                ]);

            echo $user;
            $role = Role::where('name','=','admin')->first();

            //$user->attachRole($role->id);            
            $user->roles()->attach($role->id);

            //return redirect('auth/register')->with('message','store');

        }
}
```

the `echo` on `$user` print this:

> {"name":"bbbbbvq","email":"bb@bbv.comq","active":1,"updated_at":"2016-03-03
>   19:07:24","created_at":"2016-03-03 19:07:24","id":32}

I copied entrust `Zizaco\Entrust\src\config\config.php` to my `proyect\app\config\entrust.php` and I modified the file `test\vendor\zizaco\entrust\src\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider.php` in this method:

```
  private function registerCommands()
    {
        /*
        $this->app->bindShared('command.entrust.migration', function ($app) {
            return new MigrationCommand();
        });
        $this->app->bindShared('command.entrust.classes', function ($app) {
            return new ClassCreatorCommand();
        });*/

        $this->app->singleton('command.entrust.migration', function ($app) {
            return new MigrationCommand();
        });
        $this->app->singleton('command.entrust.classes', function ($app) {
            return new ClassCreatorCommand();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your error should tell you where the error occurs (filename and line #). That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entrust hasn't been upgraded for 5.2 yet so you need to fiddle around with it a little.

As tapos gosh [has said before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34615993/1739852) you need to go in to `vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php` and on line 86:

Remove

```
$usersTable  = Config::get('auth.table');
$userModel   = Config::get('auth.model');
```

And replace it with

```
$usersTable  = Config::get('auth.providers.users.table');
$userModel   = Config::get('auth.providers.users.model');
```

And then in `config/auth.php` file write the provider line like so:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'users',
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did what you mentioned and still gives the same error.

Comment: @Jose try running `php artisan config:clear` to refresh your config settings.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me, though I did notice that some of the changes you suggested are now part of the github package.

Answer (score 7):

This resolved the issue for me.

`vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/Traits/EntrustRoleTrait.php` at line 51 makes the call  `Config::get('auth.model')` as the first parameter to the `$this->belongsToMany(` method call.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Config::get('auth.model'), ...
    // return $this->belongsToMany(Config::get('auth.model'), ...
}
```

You can either change this to `Config::get('auth.providers.users.model')` or update your `config/auth.php` file to include an entry `model => App\Users::class`

```
'model' => App\Users::class,  

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Users::class,
    ],
],
```

My preference is to update the `config/auth.php` file since any changes to the vendor folder will not be available to others on your team, or when you move to production.

Of course if you are using a different Model for your Users you would supply that instead.

Comment: Works great with 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem for **assignRole**() to the user. Solution is **role** table **guard_name** must be '

> **web**

'.